# How to read a XML Document by using DocumentBuilderFactory and DocumentBuilder?

Tags: java

I have written the following java method to read an XML File by using DocumentBuilderFactory and DocumentBuilder:

```
public static Document readAndGenerateXmlFile(String path, String fileName){

    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
    Document xmlDocument = null;
    try {
        docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        xmlDocument = docBuilder.parse(new File(path + fileName));
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException exec) {           
        logger.error(exec);
    } catch (SAXException exec) {           
        logger.error(exec);
    } catch (IOException exec) {            
        logger.error(exec);
    }       
    return xmlDocument;
}
```

Also I works with Apache Maven and using a Glassfish Application Server. The XML file, which I want to read, exists in the following path "src/main/resources/myfolder/myXmlFile.xml". The parameter for the method are "path=src/main/resources/" and "fileName=tester.xml"

The java method will be called by the following method:

```
@ManagedBean(name="mybean")
@SessionScoped
public class GuiBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeGUI(){

        Document xmlDocument = MyXmlFactory.readAndGenerateXmlFile("src/main/resources/myfolder", "myXmlFile.xml" );
        // other java code      
    }
}
```

But now I have the problem, that occurs an IOException during execute the java method above. I get the error message "The system could not found the named path". Also I can see, that the path will be extend by Java JVM (?) to "C:/Tools/myGlassfishServer/src/main/resources/myfolder/myXmlFile.xml".

Does anybody have an idea, why I get this errormessage? If I don´t started this method on an application server, the file will be founded.

Comment: Use new File(folder, file) instead of new File(folder + file) for starters

Comment: Rather use `getResourceAsStream()` since you're operating inside a container.

Comment: Adam: Your solution doesn´t work. Kayaman: Do you have a proper code example for using this inside a container?

Comment: YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/myfolder/myXmlFile.xml") can't remember if resources is included in the build or not, so you may need to try without it...

Comment: If I try the solution "YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/myfolder/myXmlFile.xml")" I get the error message "The source attachment does not contain the source for the file GlassFishInjectionProvider.class". How can I solve this problem?